# Resuming from suspend gives a blank screen

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, suspend

Ok, first I know there are many similar questions asked about this. I looked through them and tried some of the fixes. Nothing thus far has worked for me. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad B570. Running Lubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13.0-32-generic. When I close my laptop it will suspend. When I try to resume it, the screen is blank but the lights on the keyboard light up to indicate that it's awake. Prior to upgrading from 13.10, I could press the power button once and it would fully resume. Instead, it just shuts my laptop off. I'm using whatever the default driver is. Currently using the [Intel Graphics Installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) to try and see if that will make a difference. [Here](http://pastebin.com/Yy3hKs61) is my suspend log